# " sdk install java 8.0.232.hs-adpt " giving an error on ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: java, installation, sdk

each time that I try to install java through sdk, using this command: sdk install java 8.0.232.hs-adpt

I getting this error :

Stop! java 8.0.232.hs-adpt is not available. Possible causes:

- 8.0.232.hs-adpt is an invalid version
- java binaries are incompatible with your platform
- java has not been released yet

Tip: see all available versions for your platform:

I am using  ubuntu 20.04.2

Answer (score 0):

Do you need especially `java 8.0.232.hs-adpt` version?
In case you don't, this worked for me https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/03/oracle-java-16-released-install-ubuntu-20-04/.

Answer (score 0):

You can install open jdk automated but you can not install Orcale's JDK through sdk man or apt, this is because Oracle's licensing agreement of java does not allow the installation to be automated.
You have to go to the Oracle's download page and download the appropriate tar and and you can automate the install with a repository add later on if you really need it.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: What error message you are getting ? 
Please put all the details and what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **java 8.0.232.hs-adpt** is for hadoop-hdfs. I am having problem to connect to the port. Even when I have changed the port. Some people told me that it is about my java version, so I need to install it with sdk-man

I will try your solution.